# Logger in java does'nt work ,problem is in package SLF4J

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, logging, dependencies

Yooo coderrs,
have one problem with my **LOGGER** in **JAVA** with **SLF4J API Module** if i put this dependency inside of my **POM** file , so still have this issue error **java: package com.sun.org.slf4j.internal does not exist**

**My POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sk.wynny</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>hibernate</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.35</version>
    </dependency>















  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**My class**

```
import com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger;
import com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.LoggerFactory;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        logger.debug("hello world");


        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sk.hibernate");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        //saveAdress(entityManager);
        //addToTable(entityManager);
        //removeRowTable(entityManager);
        //saveName(entityManager);
        addPhone(entityManager);

        entityManager.close();


    }
```

I want just see my LOGGS,but still write me  **java: package com.sun.org.slf4j.internal does not exist**

Comment: I doubt that the package `com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger` is correct...I would suppose `org.slf4j.*` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `import`(s) for `slf4j` are wildly inaccurate. According to the [typical usage section of the manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#typical_usage), these

```
import com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.Logger;
import com.sun.org.slf4j.internal.LoggerFactory;
```

should be

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Comment: ty so much, yap they are 2different slf4j, internal and without this.